# how to sum colum row by row

Tags: php, sql

```
need to make table with asc and desc columns like below from length column.

+----------+-------+-------+-------+
|   length | ordNr | asc   | desc  |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
|    11    |  0    |   11  |   119 |
|    99    |  1    |   110 |   108 |
|    5     |  2    |   115 |   9   |
|    4     |  3    |   119 |   4   |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Can it be achieved in SQL? I know how to do it in php, but maybe javascript solution is easier?
this is how i done it [in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omaigad/UQdBF/4/)

Comment: Is this in SQL already?  If so why didn't you tag it as such?

Comment: typing "how to sum column in SQL" in the address par of your browser  takes less typing and gives an answer faster.

Comment: and why, on the earth, it is tagged with `javascript`? o_O

Comment: its not usual sum column thing or i dont see it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see how you can do this in SQL for two reasons

1. The values in the 'asc' column are dependent on the row order
2. The values in the 'desc' column can't be calculated until you have calculated the total of all the rows.

It would be much easier to read the 'length' column into an array in your programming language and handle all the necessary calculations within that array.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select max(t1._length) _length, t1._ordNr,
       sum(case when t1._ordNr >=t2._ordNr then t2._length end) _asc,
       sum(case when t1._ordNr <=t2._ordNr then t2._length end) _desc
from myTable t1 cross join myTable t2
group by t1._ordNr
```

(Underscores added to column names to avoid clashes with SQL reserved words.)